# android keydispatching timeout error

Tags: android

In my android application i used 3 imageView objects. for performing the touch action i set the touch listener and implement the opereations. when running the application it works for some touches of the imageview, after that the application hangs and finally i saw an error "keydispatching timeout". Then i implement asyncTask for the operations of imageView touch. but the problem still arises. Anybody please help me to solve this problem

Comment: can you post the contents of the onClickListener?

Comment: zoomOutView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {  
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
     zoomLevel += 1;
     if(zoomLevel <= 11){
      textView.setText("zoom:"+ zoomLevel);
      new QueueAdderZoom().execute(zoomLevel);
     }else{
     zoomLevel = 11;
     }
    }
    return true;
   }
  });      QueueAdderZoom is the asyncTask that perform adding a string to a queue. this queue is used by another thread... same method is used for second imageview with decrementing "zoom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have some long or even blocking operation in your QueueAdderZoom class's constructor or execute.

Comment: but, QueueAdderZoom is an asyncTask. how will it affect the key dispatching??

Comment: i removed the execution of QueueAdderZoom. but still it shows error. what is the meaning of this message???                  10-22 11:34:37.725: WARN/WindowManager(95): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-22 11:34:37.776: WARN/WindowManager(95): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-22 11:34:37.776: WARN/WindowManager(95): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-22 11:34:37.776: WARN/WindowManager(95): No window to dispatch pointer action 1

Comment: the key dispatching error occurs in sometimes only. and shows one more error                                                     10-22 14:30:24.109: WARN/ActivityManager(95): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44e226b8 com.ars.application/.LightVas}. Is this the reason for key dispatch error??